# For searching YouTube EDU Content using API V3

Tags: youtube-api

I am under implementing the application for searching YouTube EDU content using YouTube Data API V3.
I used below API for searching YouTube Contents, but I faced two problems.

- https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=10&order=rating&q=keyword

The first, I want to display not only title but also author, view count and total playing time.
When I use the 'part=snippet', these information is no exist in the result metadata.
So, I try to use other things that allowed at the 'part' and I get the below result.

- snippet : Well done, but author, view count and total time are not included.
- contentDetails : 400 Bad Request
- player : 400 Bad Request
- statistics : 400 Bad Request
- status : 400 Bad Request

The second, I want to search the contents within specific YouTube EDU category.
but, I can't find the proper channel_ID corresponding to 'Category' in the YouTube EDU API V2.
I referenced the below URL for getting YouTube EDU category in the API V2.

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_education#Categories

Please, help me how to resolve these problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only two supported values for the `part` parameter in `youtube.search.list()` is "snippet" and "id". What you'd need to do is keep using "snippet" and then get the video ids for each of the results (in`searchResult.id.videoId`) and then pass all up to 50 video ids into a single call to `youtube.videos.list(part="snippet,statistics,contentDetails", id="id1,id2,id3,...")` So it's two separate API calls, which is consistent with the approach we've taken in the YouTube Data API v3.

The channel id corresponding to the YouTUbe EDU category in v2 might be changing in the near future, and I'm not sure what the best way of programmatically looking that up is at this time. We should make some guidance available about that in the future and I'd recommend following the Data API v3 [revision history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history).